# Why are some Dart keywords preceded by an ampersat ('@')

Tags: dart

Ramping up on Dart and wondering why some keywords are preceded by an '@', such as @required and @override? Would obviously be cleaner if the '@' was omitted, so I'm sure its necessary, just wondering why.

EDIT

Thanks to the answer below, I see these are called annotations. I'm still confused why annotations are preceded by '@'. I come from the c++ world where "override" is a specifier and part of the language (so not proceeded by a special character). Are annotations not officially part of the dart language? I.e., why isn't "override" and "required" added to the language without the '@'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords that starts with the at sign `@` are called `annotation`. Annotations provide semantic information that tools can use to provide a better user experience. For example, an IDE might not autocomplete the name of a function that's been marked @deprecated, or it might display the function's name differently.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the "annotation" definition. I see that annotation without parameters are called marker annotations. I'm still a bit confused and will update my question.

Comment: It's not an ampersand; the OP is using an uncommon neologism to refer to the at sign.